# Delete MySQL Database selection from dropdown menu in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm currently working on a knowledge base for articles for our schools info center. Currently I'm making a page for moderators to delete articles. The page grabs all data from the "articles" table in the database to display it in a dropdown menu. The user can then select whichever and press delete. Which I intend to have said button take the selected ID and remove it from the database. However it will not delete.

Code:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo 'Select an article to delete, '.$_SESSION['username']. '<br>';
include 'index.php';

    {
        if(isset($_POST['Delete'])){
            $delete = 'DELETE FROM articles WHERE articleID IN (' . implode(',', $_POST['articles']) . ')';
            if(mysqli_query($link, $delete))
        {
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("Article was deleted!")';
            echo '</script>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'ERROR: Could not delete article';
        }
    }
}


?>


<form method="post" action="deleteArticles.php">
<select name="articles" multiple="multiple">

    <?php
    $sql=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY title");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {
        echo '<option value="' . $row['articleID'] . '">' . $row['title'] . '</option>';
    }
    ?>

</select>
<input type="submit" value="Delete" name="Delete" />
</form>
```

Comment: `The page grabs all data from the "articles" table in the database to display it in a dropdown menu. The user can then select whichever and press delete` this **very, very** bad UX

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski What would you recommend?

Comment: [*"I am presented with the error I've placed for trouble shooting"*](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49471713/1) - What you used didn't help you get the real error. Use proper error handling techniques/methods that are currently available on php.net.

Comment: Why not display as a table, with checkboxes for multiple delete or a button for single delete, it does seem strange to put it in a dropdown. You should also look into fixing the sql injection, by using prepared queries.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Currently working on a table with checkboxes right now after discussing with my group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to close your open select tag. You also didn't add multiple attribute to allow multiple selection.

```
<select name="articles" multiple="multiple">

    <?php
    $sql=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY title");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {
        echo '<option value="' . $row['articleID'] . '">' . $row['title'] . '</option>';
    }
    ?>

</select>
```

Uneeded {} wrapping removed.

**And this:**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo 'Select an article to delete, '.$_SESSION['username']. '<br>';
include 'index.php';
{

if(isset($_POST['Delete'])){
    $delete = 'DELETE FROM articles WHERE articleID IN (' . implode(',', $_POST['articles']) . ')';
    if(mysqli_query($link, $delete))
    {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Article was deleted!")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'ERROR: Could not delete article';
    }
}
}


?>
```

**To:**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo 'Select an article to delete, '.$_SESSION['username']. '<br>';
include 'index.php';

if(isset($_POST['Delete'])){
    $delete = 'DELETE FROM articles WHERE articleID IN (' . implode(',', $_POST['articles']) . ')';
    if(mysqli_query($link, $delete))
    {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Article was deleted!")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'ERROR: Could not delete article';
    }
}
?>
```

Since it is multiple selection, change select name to **articles[]**

**Like:**

```
<select name="articles[]" multiple="multiple">
```

Comment: Ah, minor error there so thank you. However problem still persists. It still wont delete selected articles.

Comment: Updated again. Select name should be articles[] since it's multiple selection.

Comment: Ok it worked! Thank you so much, I had no idea it could be the HTML that was causing this error but I've learned a lot from that.